# Which technique did I miss to improve the load time of this website? Out of wits

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, performance

I built this website [Dandy Diary](http://dandydiary.de) and I'm struggling to improve the loading time. The ratings from Pingdom are already quite good but it still takes too long to load. What is your opinion on that? What could I do better. The mobile version can be disregarded at this moment, it's not deployed yet. The site is based on Wordpress.

**What I did so far**

- Using Cloudflare
- Using several subdomains for static assets (static1-static3)
- Lazy loading the images
- Compressing and combining JS & CSS
- Caching every site to minimize hits on the DB
- The site has a left/right navigation (the arrows at the side). I preload the articles to improve the navigation speed. That works quite well, but the first load of the site is still very slow
- Loading Youtube Videos via the API
- Using SVGs where possible
- Using a JSON API for search results

One problem is that the site has so many resources (up to 1000). Since many of them are images I cannot combine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Utilise your Lazy loading more? Looks like what's already implemented is only to a small extent. A full load is ~80 requests, 9.5mb, around 40 of those are 50kb-200kb images before I've even started navigating.

Comment: You still can optimize your images...

Answer (score 2):

- **I would use lazy load much more. Currently your site is loading 77 .jpg images without even scrolling. (9.5Mb of the 10.1 Mb of the initial load)**
- Your images can still be optimized by PageSpeed saving you 211.8Kb. (2% of reduction).
- I would use sprite images instead of `.svg` files. One single sprite request will be much faster than your current 44 GET requests for individual `.svg` files.
- You can use media queries to load bigger or smaller images depending on the screen resolution (for the full screen images )

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I used SVG sprites. here is a good article on that: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ .

Answer (score 1):

@MLeFevre offers the same recommendation that I would make.

I loaded the page in Google Chrome and had the Network panel open in the developer console. It shows a LOT of individual assets/files being loaded before the page is ready. An awful lot of the wait was for all the ~240Kb jpg files that are loaded.

Moving your JS, CSS and images to a CDN is a good option for up to 25% page load improvement but reducing the number of files loaded is going to make the biggest difference. As suggested, if you move all the images into the lazy load functionality - only loading what is needed "in view" then your visitors will see a fast page load. Then you load them as they are scrolled into view.

Look at whether the images can be compressed any more too. It's a trade off but most people won't notice a bit more compression, but they will notice the page loading slowly.